# How to empty FileWriter output before appending new data?

Tags: java, csv, filewriter, file-writing

When ever I run the program again it simply appends to the existing file.

I want to empty the file and then start with the business logic

```
FileWriter empty = new FileWriter("output.csv", true); //true = append
empty.write("");
empty.close();

FileWriter outfile = new FileWriter("output.csv", true); //true = append
// Add desired content
outfile.flush();
outfile.close();
```

Comment: but you are constructiing the object to do so: ***FileWriter("output.csv", true)***

Answer (score 2):

but you are constructing the object to do so: `FileWriter("output.csv", true)`

the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter-java.lang.String-boolean-) explains what the boolean value do in the file:

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean
>   indicating whether or not to append the data written.

set that boolean parameter to false in order to overwrite the file...

```
FileWriter("output.csv", false)
```

or simple:

```
FileWriter("output.csv")
```

Comment: If i set the first one to false then the second FileWriter doesn't append even if it set it to true...

Comment: @santafebound Then why you just don't open the file with `true` on second time.

Answer (score 1):

To make it empty, you can overwrite it and you need to use a **single** file.

The `empty` `FileWriter` is not required.

Specify the append `parameter` to false in the `public FileWriter(File file, boolean append)` constructor call or better don't specify it by using the   `public FileWriter(String fileName)` constructor.
 By default it overwrites the file :

```
FileWriter outfile = new FileWriter("output.csv");
```

Answer (score 1):

Thing is:

```
FileWriter outfile = new FileWriter("output.csv", true); //true = append
```

creates a FileWriter that **appends** to an existing file.

```
FileWriter outfile = new FileWriter("output.csv", false);
```

creates a FileWriter that will **overwrite** any content that is currently in that file.

Those are the two options you have!

But the real answer here: read the javadoc of the classes you are using, this behavior is **explicitly** [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).

And just for the record: this is one of the reasons why one should be *really* careful about using booleans parameters as "flags". I agree; for a newbie, having that "true" sitting there doesn't say anything.

A "better" interface could be used like:

```
FileWriter empty = new FileWriter("output.csv", FileWriterMode.APPEND);
```

And as your requirements seems to be: you want to **blank** that output file; and then write data to it ... simply forget about appending. In essence, you are asking: how do I overwrite my CSV file with new content. And then the answer is - you do not need that "empty" writer; just go with:

```
FileWriter outfile = new FileWriter("output.csv", false);
```

By doing so; you always overwrite what is currently in the output file; then you add content.

Comment: When I do this I see my file size oscillate between 0 and 1kb. and the output has a single line...

Comment: Thanks but my problem is that I do want to append everything in the second FileWriter. The first one should overwrite the file and make it blank and the second one should continue by adding new lines until the program stops.

Comment: I see. Because when I run the program again it just appends more lines to the existing csv file.